# Key generating program in Python

Tags: python

I am about two months into programming with Python (no previous experience) and I tried to write a program which would generate a key and assign it to a student.

```
import random
import string


code_list = []
students = ["Aljoša", "Blažka", "Nana", "Kaja", "Alja", "Tjaša", "Ana",
           "Gal", "Danijela", "Alma", "Neja", "Žiga K.", "Patricija", "Aja",
           "Kristjan",  "Urban",  "Janja", "Lea", "Žana", "Aljaž", "Tilen",
           "Matic", "Marija", "Žiga T."]

#It generates the code and puts it in a list
size = 6
code = string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits
for i in range(24):
    code_list.append(str(''.join(random.choice(code) for _ in range(size))))

#Combines the two lists (students and codes) into one
students_plus_codes = [x + str(" - " + y) for y in students for x in 
                      code_list]

#It prints only every 25th element from the combined list
new = [x for i, x in enumerate(students_plus_codes) if i % 25 == 0]

for i in new:
    print(i)`
```

My problem is that this code is not very elegant and just want to ask how I could write it more efficiently (especially the last part where I have to manually print out every 25th element of a list because every key gets assigned to every student).

Answer (score 6):

The reason that you are getting so many more entries is because of this list comprehension:

```
 students_plus_codes = [x + str(" - " + y) for y in students for x in code_list]
```

It's a nested `for` loop. If we expand it we can see what is happening:

```
students_plus_codes = []
for y in students:  # students has 24 items
    for x in code_list:  # code_list has 24 items
        students_plus_codes.append(x + str(" - " + y))
```

So for every iteration of `students` you do 24 iterations of `code_list`.

Fortunately, python has a builtin function called [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) that will merge lists for us. So we can replace the nested list comprehension with this line:

```
students_plus_codes = list(zip(students, code_list))
```

Which results in a list of tuples:

```
[('Aljoša', '256D2B'), ('Blažka', 'OEGJL9'), ('Nana', 'GB1PJL'), ('Kaja', 'F0P0F2'), 
 ('Alja', '62KU94'), ... ('Matic', 'E7CJIP'), ('Marija', '1D2UCL'), ('Žiga T.', '6X1DD5')]
```

#### Generating the codes:

First, I would replace `for i in range(24):` with `for i in range(len(students)):` as this allows you to change the number of students without having to change other aspects of your code. In this instance `24` is a [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) that could cause issues down the line.

You could even create a function that generates each code, then you can use an easy to read list comprehension.

```
# <=python3.5
def generate_code(n, characters):
    return ''.join([random.choice(characters) for _ in range(n)]) 

# >=python3.6
def create_code(n, characters):
    return ''.join(random.choices(characters, k=n))
```

#### Printing the codes:

It isn't ideal to join the names and codes as a single string as this makes it hard to use them separately later. For this reason, I used a list of tuples to match them as pairs. To print them the `for` loop has two variables, `student` and `code` that takes advantage of [unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) and then prints them using the [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) function.

```
for student, code in students_plus_codes:
    print('{} - {}'.format(code, student))
```

---

#### Altogether:

```
import random
import string


def create_code(n, characters):
    return ''.join(random.choices(characters, k=n))


students = ["Aljoša", "Blažka", "Nana", "Kaja", "Alja", "Tjaša", "Ana",
           "Gal", "Danijela", "Alma", "Neja", "Žiga K.", "Patricija", "Aja",
           "Kristjan",  "Urban",  "Janja", "Lea", "Žana", "Aljaž", "Tilen",
           "Matic", "Marija", "Žiga T."]

# It generates the code and puts it in a list
key_size = 6
chars = string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits
code_list = [create_code(key_size, chars) for _ in range(len(students))]

# Combines the two lists (students and codes) into a list of tuples
students_plus_codes = list(zip(students, code_list))

for student, code in students_plus_codes:
    print('{} - {}'.format(code, student))
```

Comment: Thank you, this was really helpful, I would never figure it out on my own :D

Comment: I'm glad it's helped. For a next step, I would check that a key hasn't already been generated. As you have a character space of 36 and string length of 6 there are `36^6` possible codes, which is _a lot_, but it's still possible there could be a collision!

Comment: oh cool, and how would i do that exacty? I am really that new to all this yeah haha

Comment: @urbanpečoler, python has an object type called [`sets`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) that doesn't allow duplicates. You could add your keys to a set until it reaches the desired length using a while loop.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with the points from @Alex answer,

- [with PEP506](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0506/) there is a Python module for generating keys [secrets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html)
- `size` is a [constant (PEP8 naming styles)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles) and should be `UPPER_SNAKE_CASE`

---

```
import secrets
from string import digits, ascii_uppercase

SIZE = 6

def create_code(n, characters):
    return ''.join(secrets.choice(characters) for _ in range(n))

print(create_code(SIZE, digits + ascii_uppercase))
```